# jstree - how to get instance?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have the following code:

```
model.tree = $('#container').jstree({
    'core': { 'data': r, 'check_callback': true },
    'plugins': ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu", "dnd", "types"],
    'contextmenu': {
            "select_node": "true",
            "items": function($node) {
                return {
                    create: {
                        'label': "Create",
                        'action': function(obj) {
                            this.create(obj); // this = Window
                            model.tree.create(obj); // model.tree doesnt contain "create" method
                        }
                    },
                };
            }
    },
});
```

I am writing a custom handler for Create contextmenu action like it's shown in the examples, but i can't call this.create as "this" is the Window object. ALso i tried to use my jstree instance to call "create" but it doesnt contain that method as well.
How do i call "create" method to create a node? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"items": function($node) {
    var tree = $("#container").jstree(true);
    return {
        create: {
            'label': "Create",
            'action': function(obj) {
                $node = tree.create_node($node);
                tree.edit($node);
            }
        },
    };
}
```